# Согласование времен

Tags: морфология, согласование, глаголы

Есть ли в русском языке строгие правила согласования времён?
Например в предложении *Стороннему наблюдателю было трудно заметить изменения, происшедшие в его жизни, ведь они не касаются внешнего*
оправдано ли использование настоящего времени "касаются"? или лучше прошедшее — "касались"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абстрактные закономерности можно описывать и в настоящем, так как они как бы существуют вне времени.

То есть эти изменения, хоть они уже и прошли, существуют и в данный момент как отпечаток во времени. Таким образом, можно вполне использовать настоящее.

Более очевидный пример:
*Он решил проблему интересным способом, но само решение не касается математики.* || Хоть решение и было совершено, но оно абстрактно существует и в данный момент. Настоящее время лучше звучит и уместнее.

Прошедшее точно нужно употреблять при изменении: если они не касались внешнего, а теперь уже касаются.

Время следует выбирать по звучанию и ориентируясь по временной привязке: не касались внешнего именно на тот момент или не касаются в общем, а момент не важен.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, в русском нет такого согласования времён, как в английском, и ваше "касаются" в настоящем времени вполне имеет право на существование. Однако в данном случае его можно оправдать, на мой взгляд, только в том случае, если верно то, что ***любые*** изменения, происходящие в жизнях людей, не касаются внешнего. Если это сильное обобщение действительно имеет место, тогда лишь настоящее время можно употребить.